# cleaning up dynamically added fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

Code below is simplified, only the relevant stuff is shown.

I have in a layout XML file:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/top_row"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"/>
```

This layout is inflated in a `Fragment` in a `ViewPager` using a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`

In the `onCreateView()` of the `Fragment` we want to add child fragments dynamically, can be any kind of number. So we do this:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.the_layout, container, false);

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

for(Fragment f : fragments) {
    transaction.add(R.id.top_row, frag);
}

transaction.commit();
```

Works perfectly, all the fragments nicely aligned next to each other.

But here is the problem: whenever the `Activity`'s onCreate is being called again, the `ViewPager` is being set to a new `Adapter`. So I'd expect everything to be rebuild again. 
So the `onCreateView` is called, so a new `View` is created and the `Fragments` are added to this new `LinearLayout`.

What actually happens, is that the previous `Fragments` still seem to exist! The new `Fragments` are added to the previous added `Fragments`. So let's say there are 3 `Fragments`, after `onCreateView()` has been called 3 times, I have 9.

What I think what is happening: the `Fragments` are associated by ID with the `View`, so they will be added to the new `View` too.
What I think I should do: remove all `Fragments` in the `onDestroyView()`, but this is not allowed (generates an 'this can not be done after `onSaveInstanceState()`, in `onPause()` generates a crash).

Is this something that should not be done this way? Should I use a layout with `FrameLayout`s and use `FragmentTransaction.replace()` on these?

My `Activity` has no other functions implemented except `onCreate()`. Here it instantiates the adapter and sets it on the `ViewPager`

The `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` itself is very simple at the moment, `getItem()` just returns the specific `Fragment`:

```
return new MyFragment();
```

Comment: According to the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle), it is not possible for fragments, to live longer than their parent activities. You should check, whether your activity implements onCreate() and onStart() correctly. Please paste that code here. I'd say, remove the fragments during onStop(), add fragments during onStart().

Comment: will throw a 'java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState' at 'transaction.commit()'

Comment: If you don't show more code from your activity lifecycle, it's hard to give any hints. Alternatively, @Override onSaveInstanceState() and set a Breakpoint in this method, to see when it is called and what your fragments state is at that time.

Comment: Added some more info, activity implements nothing except onCreate, the Pager only returns one fragment at the moment.

Comment: Maybe i see something: your activity is not actually terminated when leaving it, so the PageAdapter is kept alive as it should be. The onCreateView() method could be called more than once, so your fragment stack grows. You should try, if moving the fragment transaction from onCreateView() to onActivityCreated() works better/as expected.

Comment: tried it, but as I expected, no difference. The onActivityCreated() is always being called after onCreateView(). So different effect would not be expected

Comment: When adding a fragment, give it a unique tag. Then, before creating a new instance of fragment, try to find that fragment in fragment manager by tag. If it's there, return that instance, otherwise create a new one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What I think I should do: remove all Fragments in the onDestroyView()

don't do that. it won't do any good.

not sure that you know it or not - if your your `Activity` is re-created without explicitly been destroyed previously from calling finish() or or pressing the back button - it means that it [restored from previous instance state](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html).

in that case, you should not perform the transaction again, because - it already happens automatically via the super.onCreate() Activity method.  in fact, if you'll perform the fragment trasaction in that case - you'll cause the same fragment  to be added twice (2 instances)

you can know if currently `onCreate()`  been called from restoring instance state by checking if `savedInstanceState` parameter is null or not.

**you are not checking `savedInstanceState`, and performing the transaction anyway.**

if I'm right, then the following change should fix the fragment duplication problem:

instead of:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

for(Fragment f : fragments) {
    transaction.add(R.id.top_row, frag);
}

transaction.commit();
```

write:

```
 if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    for(Fragment f : fragments) {
        transaction.add(R.id.top_row, frag);
    }

    transaction.commit();
}
```

more info at - http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: I haven't had time to try this (project pressure) but will do later! I will give you the bounty reward anyway

Comment: @boy: thanks, I see that you accepted the answer, but did not reward the bounty yet

Comment: ah yes..did it now..sorry :)